# SQL group by can't find correct phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a simple design

```
id | grpid | main
-----------------
1  |   1   |  1
2  |   1   |  0
3  |   1   |  0
4  |   2   |  0
5  |   2   |  1
6  |   2   |  0
```

The question to answer is

```
What is the "id" of the main in each group?
```

The result should be

```
id
---
1
5
```

Seriously at the moment, I'm not able to answer it on my own. Pls assist me.

Comment: if you just want id `select id from t where main=1` ?

Comment: Dude u are totally correct, I was so blinded because of the need to group but it isn't necessary. if u could post this as an answer I would accept it. Thx

Comment: You should probably delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way you can do this with:

```
select id from <table_name> where main=1
```

but as you have mentioned you want `id` with group by `grpid` below query will work.

```
select id from <table_name> group by grpid, main having main = 1
```

You have to apply `group by` on your group id and based on that check the value of main as 1. You will get the desired result.

Comment: That doesn't work. Error: Column 'table.main' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: add this in group by `group by grpid, main`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i'm oversimplifying it here but couldn't you just do this:

```
select id,
       grpid
  from table
 where main = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a column for its corresponding "MainId" then you can do this perhaps?

```
SELECT f.id, f.grpid, f.main, t.MainId
FROM foo f
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT grpid, id AS MainId 
    FROM foo f1
    WHERE main = 1
        AND f.grpid = f1.grpid) t
```